# Edit UITableViewCell inline in same view controller

Tags: ios

I have a table view controller where I show a shopping bag (or shopping cart). In each cell I show an image view, an a few labels with some information. One of those labels shows the quantity of products for that product. I want that when I press the edit button the quantity label becomes a stepper (or something like that) where I can change the quantity. I have seen that behavior on other apps (specific on Zara for iPhone, a clothes store) but I cannot figure out how to do that. All I have found on the internet is to segue to another view where you can edit an item, but that's not what I want to do.

How is it possible to implement such a behavior?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the stepper on the label, in the UITableView Method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

This method allows you to perform actions when a table view cell is selected.